# how to remove default border/outline from image

Tags: html, image

hey guys i want to know that how to remove border/outline from image tag, include that i am not using image in it , for example [test code fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vishalvarshney/h38yhc48/7/)

HTML

```
<img src="" class="testClass">
```

CSS

```
.testClass{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    height: 150px;
    border: 0px;
    outline : none;
}
```

Comment: thats ok what you do, i do not understand you.

Comment: If you're not using an image, don't use an img tag. The display of missing images is very browser dependent and you shouldn't plan on controlling it.

Comment: oh, i did not realized, he do not use image. sorry.

Comment: @ScottSaunders is right. If you absolutely must have an image tag that points to a broken URL (or non-existant, like #), then try instead pointing it to a blank.gif.

Comment: If your trying to catch broken images check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/92720/2033671

Comment: i have to add image source dynamically, so i have to compulsorily put img tag there

Answer (score 2):

What you see there is the browser's "broken image URL" image. That's what you get when the browser can't load the image. It doesn't have a border; the browser just renders something so you can see how big the missing image would be. Therefore, you can't influence the result with CSS much.

What you can do is set `display: none` to hide the image altogether. If you want the space to be empty, wrap it in a `div` with the same size.

Comment: i have to add image source dynamically, so i have to compulsorily put img tag there

Comment: @vishal - if the img has no image path you could remove the image completely with `img[src=""] { display: none }` (IE 8 +) [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/tbjjzjj8/)

Comment: @vishal: Try this: Put an empty DIV there and create the whole `img` element dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Display none would remove the image, so it destroys the space it occupies, not good for the layout. Also it causes a map with areas to be inaccesible. I use an empty image to create some clickable areas for some underlying elements, so I don't want an image.
The only option that works is to set opacity to 0.